# How to post two variables with jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to post two variables with jQuery AJAX?  One variable work fine but two variables not working

```
function get() {
    $('#age').hide();
    $.post('jrecomment2.php',{ userID: form.userID.value },{ id_number: form.id_number.value }

    function(output){

        $('#age').html(output).slideDown(2000);


        });

}
```

and  the form:

```
<form name="form" dir="rtl">
    <input type="text" name="userID">
    <input type="text" name="id_number">
    <input type="button" value="submit" style=" width: 120;" onClick="get();"> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `{ userID: form.userID.value, id_number: form.id_number.value }`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('jrecomment2.php',{ userID: form.userID.value, id_number: form.id_number.value }, function(output){ });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'jrecomment2.php',
            data: 'userID=' + form.userID.value+'&id_number='+form.id_number.value,
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (output) {

            $('#age').html(output).slideDown(2000);
            }
        });
```

and post method

```
$.post('jrecomment2.php',{ userID: form.userID.value, id_number:     form.id_number.value }, function(output)
 { 
   $('#age').html(output).slideDown(2000);
 }
);
```